# How to retrieve the xml value using the xpath?

Tags: java, excel

My Scenario : I may get the different outputs which is shown below.I want to retrieve the "Units" tag value depends on Code tag.

Output1 :

```
<Riders>
<Rider>
  <Name>ALSP</Name>
  <Code>ALSP</Code>
  <Units>3</Units>
</Rider>
<Rider>
  <Name>Individual</Name>
  <Code>Select Type of Coverage</Code>
  <OptionCode>Individual</OptionCode>
  <IsFeature>true</IsFeature>
</Rider>
</Riders>
```

Output2 :

```
<Riders>
<Rider>
  <Name>AFO</Name>
  <Code>AFO</Code>
  <Units>6</Units>
</Rider>
<Rider>
  <Name>Individual</Name>
  <Code>Select Type of Coverage</Code>
  <OptionCode>Individual</OptionCode>
  <IsFeature>true</IsFeature>
</Rider>
</Riders>
```

I have tried below xpath but didn't worked out. Could anyone suggest me.

```
/Riders/Rider/Code[text()[contains(.,'AFO')]  or text()     [contains(.,'ALSP')]]/Units
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on if you want to get the node with regards to the root or just find any matching node, you could use something like...

```
*/Rider[Code[contains(.,'ALSP')]]/Units
```

Which will return you all the `Units` nodes which belong to any `Rider` node, which have a `Code` node, whose text contains `ALSP`

Of course you could also use...

```
*/Rider[Code[text() = 'ALSP']]/Units
```

If the `Code` must match exactly.

The above will find all the `Units` nodes of the `Rider` node anywhere in the document.  If the position is important, you would need to replace `*/` with `/Riders/` instead.

Now, if you want to find both `ALSP` and `AFO`, you could use something like...

```
*/Rider[Code[text() = 'ALSP' or text() = 'AFO']]/Units
```